# Creating a different sequence using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, sequence

I am new to python and self-learning on my own time. 
I learned some basic tricks to print the next following.

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I found 3 ways to do it. And they are:

**1**

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

for j in reversed (range(1, number+1)):
    for i in reversed (range(1, o+1)):
        print ("* ", end='')
    print ('')
```

**2**

```
for j in range(number):
    for i in  (range(number-o)):
        print ("* ", end='')
    print ('')
```

**3**

```
for j in range(number+1):
    number = number - 1
    for i in  (range(number+1)):
        print ("* ", end='')
    print ('')
```

Either of 3 works. But my question is how should I make the code so that it prints.

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can append a number of spaces to the beginning of the string the same way you add asterisks.

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for j in range(number):
    for i in range(j):
        print("  ", end='')
    for i in range(number - j):
        print("* ", end='')
    print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could try

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

for j in range(number):
      print((" " * (j)) + ("*" * (number-j)))
```

This way you can handle everything in one loop and it's easy to make sense of it quickly.  You simply print out a space j times and a "*" number-j times through each iteration of the loop.

You could use a similar technique to print out the triangle in the way you did in your post.  Here would be a 4th way for you to check out.

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

for j in range(number):
      print(("*" * (j+1)) + (" " * (number)))
```